# Can I avoid react-router forcing two renders on initial load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using React Router where I need to send props down to the component I'm rendering. Due to this, I'm using this format:

```
<Route exact path={ROUTES.HOME} component={() => <HomeAuth ga={ga} />} />
```

This format for `component=` is causing `componentDidMount` to be run, and it then un-mounts before mounting again. This is a problem because I have a few promises that return after the un-mounting, meaning they're returning to a component that doesn't and will never exist anymore.

This implementation of component works for me, but I don't know if it's possible to pass props to it. Is there any way for me to either use the format above and avoid the second mounting, or pass props to this format?:

```
<Route exact path={ROUTES.HOME} component={HomeAuth} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! This is possible with render= instead of component= as written here: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/

This doesn't create a new component on each render (because why should it!)

What a nightmare component= is!